# Allow user to dynamically add fields and values to a node in Drupal

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to come up with a way for a user to populate a form with only the fields needed for a given piece of content.

So for example I have a content type called "Research Project" and I want to add a series of measurements to each one.

eg.
Proj 1:
Water Sampling

Measurements:
Gallons of water collected - 20 gal

Ambient temperature at time of collection - 75 deg F

PPM lead found in water - 2 ppm

The measurements criteria would be entered into the system ahead of time and they would select it from a dropdown. I imagine the UI would look like this for the form:

select measurement from dropdown >  Field to enter value
+ link to add unlimited new measurement and value rows

The measurements are variable from project to project, there's a lot of them and there's always new ones being added making it impractical to add every potential measurement as it's own CCK field. There's also too many different types of project to make content types for each project practical. So essentially I'm looking for the ability to build the form and populate results on the fly. How should I go about doing this? I could input my measurements as taxonomy terms, but then how could I assign and store a value for each?

Answer (score 0):

there is two functions

field_create_field() can create field a itself.

field_create_instance() - binds a field to the bundle.
Example [from this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/assign-fields-programatically-to-custom-node-defined-by-custom-module):

```
$field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_' . $vocabulary->machine_name, 
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
    'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED, 
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array(
        array(
          'vocabulary' => $vocabulary->machine_name, 
          'parent' => 0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  field_create_field($field);

  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_' . $vocabulary->machine_name, 
    'entity_type' => 'node', 
    'label' => 'Tags', 
    'bundle' => 'article', 
    'description' => $vocabulary->help, 
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'taxonomy_autocomplete', 
      'weight' => -4,
    ), 
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link', 
        'weight' => 10,
      ), 
      'teaser' => array(
        'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link', 
        'weight' => 10,
      ),
    ),
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
```